# How can I winterize an old solid concrete factory with a cargo elevator?

Tags: winterizing

Looking to find the best methods using economical (low budget) materials.

Note: "Green-friendly" is a plus.

Also, I'm interested in hearing & learning about materials & methods that promote longevity.

1. I'm living in a 3rd floor raw factory space. 3000 square feet & drafty. Concrete floors, walls, & ceiling. The windows are single pane measuring in at 6" x 4"6' with an additional 2", sometimes 3", of old cheap plywood. The window framing is basically 10'x6'. Ideally I'd install double pane windows or frame and insulate these 10'x6' areas with 2"x4"s, insulation, & plywood. 
   So far I've  caulked & used spray foam in the window area to cover, obviously, any holes & cracks that'd allow cold air to enter. Then I hung heavy duty plastic, sometimes using silicone for additional adhesive, with a staple gun. Plus I stapled carpet padding thinking this would help due to heavy, fiber, absorbent, fabric.
2. I'm replacing factory glass panes in the cargo elevator shaft using putty. After 24-48 hours I'm using oil paint to help seal & dry. Now I've started to caulk around the old windows & putty for additional sealing. Chances are I will oil paint these areas, however, I don't know if it will necessarily help.

I plan to use liquid nails & plastic to cover these windows in the elevator shaft however I considering foam cut outs.

1. The elevator door on my floor: plastic, foam,...?

Plastic dominates my thoughts as far as a solution goes.

Other solutions would be to build partitions but $ is an issue. Plus I'm looking to avoid zoning laws from the city of Chi until further research.

I do have one wall built in the back with 2 rooms that was built before I occupied the space. I've used spray foam & caulked all cracks to avoid heat from my 2 space heaters leaving the area. Carpet & rugs are laid out in these two rooms, help with temperature regulation.

Comment: I'm having a hard time isolating the question or questions here. perhaps you could emphasize them for us?

Comment: I came here because I couldn't imagine how someone would use a cargo elevator to winterize a factory. There's only two things to worry about. Limit heat loss with insulation and limiting infiltration by sealing. If the floor above is unheated (or the roof), ceiling insulation is most important.